# Babel-node script failed with 'Unexpected token' syntaxError on 'await' line

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, babeljs

I have a script that's reading a bunch of info from Firebase, and `then` processes it. This involves some async calls to external data sources, for which I want to use `async` and `await`. I've done this successfully, in this very npm project, so I don't see why it's not working now. This is my .babelrc file:

```js
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-async-functions","transform-regenerator"]
}
```

And this is the gist of my code:

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "myProject.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myProject.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "myProject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "id"
};
Firebase.initializeApp(config);

var dbRef = Firebase.database().ref();

getAllFirebaseDocs(dbRef);

async function getAllFirebaseDocs(dbRef) {
 return dbRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var items = snapshot.val();
        for (key in items) {
            var priceUrl = "some.url.com"
      items[key] = await requestPrices(items[key], priceUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

It's failing on the `await` line with `SyntaxError: testScript.js: Unexpected token`. And a bunch of code with weird box characters and 33m and 39m in it, like this: `[33m][39m[1m,[22m priceUrl[94m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m`.

I'm running the script with `babel-node testScript.js`. I know this works, since I have another script that I run in the same project with `babel-node` and it has async parts that work fine... not sure what I've missed in this one. If it matters, `babel-node -V` gives v6.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `await` within functions that are marked `async`. In your case, you're running it inside a function (the callback to `.then()`) that isn't marked as such.

You can use this:

```
return dbRef.once('value').then(async function(snapshot) { ... });
```

But since you're using `async/await` already, you might as well rewrite your code to this:

```
async function getAllFirebaseDocs(dbRef) {
  let snapshot = await dbRef.once('value');
  let items    = snapshot.val();
  for (let key in items) {
    let priceUrl = "some.url.com"
    items[key] = await requestPrices(items[key], priceUrl);
  }
  // I assume that you want to return `items`; your original code doesn't return anything.
  return items;
}
```

Comment: In both cases (the inline async and rearranged async), it gives me a new error: `You gave us a visitor for the node type "ForAwaitStatement" but it's not a valid type`. Doesn't give me a line number on which this is occurring.

Comment: Ah, I solved it; upgraded my babel-core to 6.18.2 and removed 'stage-0' from my .babelrc file. Now my script works, thanks :)